# Print from keyword to end of sequence when sequence is multiple lines

Tags: python, parsing, sequence

How do I print from a line (from a .txt file in a single column array with newline seperated values) to the end of the sequence which is a few lines long but not always the same amount of lines.

Using python 3.3.

I only want the sequence for some of the data entries the ones that contain a keyword

I was thinking something line this:

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        cache.append(line)

    for line in range(len(cache)):
        if 'keyword' in cache[line].lower():
            print line

#however i need to print the next line which is the start of the sequence and 
#continue this until the end (I guess this could be ' " ' or 'keyword2')
```

Thankyou

Comment: Can you post an example of the input data and show the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
f=open('toto2.txt','r')
    for line in f:
        if 'keyword' in line:
            print line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kw0='d'
kw1='q'

with open('fn.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if kw0 in line:
            print(line)
            for nextline in f:
                print(nextline)
                if kw1 not in nextline:
                    break
```

A bit nested, but as you use the same f it should work. Could put the print function after if block if you do not want to show line with `kw1`.

Example using file:

```
a b c
d e f
d e f
g h i
abq
123 abc
d
q
```

We get output:

```
d e f
d e f
g h i
abq
d
q
```

Best part is: no need to cache everything.

Could use `print(line,end='')` or `print(line.strip())` to avoid newlines between prints.